# Protect key used to decrypt encrypted database with sqlcipher in Android app

Tags: android, passwords, android-sqlite, sqlcipher

I am developing an android application that contains a database previously encrypted SQLCipher in the "assets" directory. This SQLite database is copied from the directory "assets" to the application data directory.

The application makes use of SQLCipher to decrypt and access the data from the database, but the problem is that the key to the database is stored in a String, which, if someone decompile the APK file can be obtained the key.

Is there any way to protect the key to not be able to get that key to decompile the APK?

PS If you do not understand me, do not write well in English, because I am Spanish.

Comment: SQLCipher is designed for protecting a user's data, and the passphrase used with SQLCipher is supposed to come from a user. SQLCipher is not a DRM solution, as you are trying to use it here.

Comment: The password does not come from any user, it is contained in a String of the application. What I want is to protect a database which is previously encrypted outside the application and put it in the application so that it makes use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We provide some guidance on key material and selection [here](http://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-database-key-material-and-selection/25) for SQLCipher, please note that hardcoding a key in application code is not suitable for any secure implementation.